# Multimedia keys and wine

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wine, mediaplayer

I run AIMP audio player with wine and can not use special multimedia keys like play/pause, next/prev.

IS there any way to make them work with wine?

For example: Fn+F9, Fn+f10, Fn+F8...

Comment: @intika yes, KDE5 5.63, Plasma 5.17

Comment: You could also use xmodmap to map the keys, but it would on your machine, which appears to be not exactly what you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With KDE 5, you can open the settings panel of kde `systemsettings5` then under `Shortcuts` select `Custom Shortcuts`, right click on the panel of the the middle where the shortcuts are listed and select `New` > `Global Shortcut` > `Command/URL` keep the new entry checked (active) on the right panel select `Trigger` pane then click `None` then press the key you want to assign to let say pause then under `Action` pane put the following in the box then click apply to save the settings.

```
/usr/bin/wine "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AIMP\\AIMP.exe" /next
```

Adapt the path if you use different location for wine or AIMP.exe

Repeat the operation for the rest of the actions, here are the proper commands

```
/usr/bin/wine "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AIMP\\AIMP.exe" /play
/usr/bin/wine "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AIMP\\AIMP.exe" /pause
/usr/bin/wine "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AIMP\\AIMP.exe" /prev
/usr/bin/wine "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AIMP\\AIMP.exe" /stop
```

Here is a [video demonstrating](https://youtu.be/RhO2yxE4Qpw?t=38) how to add custom shortcuts in KDE

You may experience a little delay because of how the app is instructed to pause/play etc... but this should not be a big issue.

Shortcuts can be customized on the AIMP app itself but it will only work when the app is active.

Note that if you assign your true media key to this purpose they won't work anymore on linux native applications or you can make them work on both by executing 2 commands separated by `;` or you can execute a script that check if AIMP is running and do the proper action from there.

Comment: Thank you! that works great. Too bad if a wine app can't react to native global media shotcuts. I noticed that when gwenview and VLC both opened the priority goes to VLC and if VLC isn't opened, then for some reason gewnview slideshow starts (even though there are no shortcut for it anywhere). Would be nice if I could add wine to the list of media-keys listeners.

Comment: I'm struggling to make the true media keys work for both the wine application and still working under regular linux applications. any hints on how you do this? what would I need to call as a second command?